# Is there a solution to upload 3D glTF model on website server to get individual link to send client

Tags: 3d, e-commerce, blender, gltf

I am not IT designer. I'm looking for website where I can upload on a server my GLTF file and get individual link to share it with my customers. Do you know such a website? Quality is important.
Thanks

I like https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ design and quality.

Comment: Are you looking for something like SketchFab? https://sketchfab.com/